# El Capitan : How to disable Force Click "Dictionary Pop-ups" in Chrome?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, trackpad, dictionary

In my Chrome Browser, whenever i "Force Click" (hard clicked by one finger) upon a Word, the dictionary lookup Pop-up is always popping out.

Like this:

[image]

I have already DISABLED the "Force Click" setting in the Trackpad Settings:

[image]

And then already Restarted the Chrome. And also did (related or not) the:

```
$ killall SystemUIServer
```

But this annoying **pop-up (Dictionary Lookup) is still there**. I'm sure it is not a Chrome Extension.

What should i do to totally get rid of that, please?

Thank you all!

Comment: For clarity, "Look up & data detectors" and the `killall SystemUIServer` is unnecessary/irrelevant - just uncheck "Force Click and haptic feedback" (see @Scott answer below)

Answer (score 34):

Switch 'Look up & Data Detectors' to 3-finger tap.  You can then re-enable it.  This avoids disabling force touch entirely.

Comment: what about iMac?

Comment: This was helpful, thanks. It doesn't seem like Force Click is all that helpful though, seems like it only applies to quick preview in finder and some media controls which I haven't seen.

Answer (score 19):

You have to also uncheck "Force Click and haptic feedback" at the bottom of the Trackpad Point & Click settings.